# Parallel stadium of Pipeline and Multiplexer 2:1

Tags: vhdl, pipeline, cpu-architecture, fpga

I have a Spartan-E3 FPGA and I'm realizing a (parallel) pipeline with 4 stages like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WTTP.png

The two stages "T3" are the same. T1, T2 and T4 "run" at 50MHz, while T3 runs at 25MHz (and 180° shifted like in the figure).

In Behavioral Simulation it works fine, the results are correct. The problem occurs when I try to synthesize this project on my FPGA. In particular I receive these warnings (and offcourse the results produced are wrong):

```
WARNING:LIT:175 - Clock buffer is designated to drive clock loads. BUFGMUX
symbol "physical_group_clk_2/Clock_DCM/CLKFX_BUFG_INST" (output signal=clk_2)
has a mix of clock and non-clock loads. Some of the non-clock loads are
(maximum of 5 listed):
Pin I0 of pipeline/mux3/o<65>1
Pin I0 of pipeline/mux3/o<64>1
Pin I0 of pipeline/mux3/o<17>
Pin I0 of pipeline/mux3/o<18>
Pin I0 of pipeline/mux3/o<20>
WARNING:Route:455 - CLK Net:clk_2 may have excessive skew because 
0 CLK pins and 66 NON_CLK pins failed to route using a CLK template.
```

Where "clk_2" is the CLOCK 25MHz.
This is "my multiplexer": stage_4_in <= stage_3_1_out when clk_2='1' else stage_3_2_out;

Basically I can't drive the Multiplexer Selection with a clock signal. So, how can I do it?
I have to do this: if CLOCK 25MHz is high the mux output has to be the top one; otherwise it has to be the second one (bottom). I couldn't figure out how to do this.

By the way, this is the DCM configuration:

```
CLK_FEEDBACK => "1X",
CLKDV_DIVIDE => 2.0,
CLKFX_DIVIDE => 4,
CLKFX_MULTIPLY => 2,
CLKIN_DIVIDE_BY_2 => FALSE,
CLKIN_PERIOD => 20.000,
CLKOUT_PHASE_SHIFT => "NONE",
DESKEW_ADJUST => "SYSTEM_SYNCHRONOUS",
DFS_FREQUENCY_MODE => "LOW",
DLL_FREQUENCY_MODE => "LOW",
DUTY_CYCLE_CORRECTION => TRUE,
FACTORY_JF => x"C080",
PHASE_SHIFT => 0,
STARTUP_WAIT => TRUE
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate the 25MHz clock - run the whole lot off the 50MHz clock, with clock enables during the even and odd 50MHz cycles for the stages you want to run at 25 MHz. (The culrrent 25MHz clock would probably serve as the clock enable signal)